# difference between VARCHAR NVARCHAR in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar  in SQLite

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Microsoft SQL Server, VARCHAR is ASCII and NVARCHAR is Unicode (UTF-16). In SQLite, all text is Unicode, so it's not relevant. In any case, SQLite is loosely typed so it wouldn't make a difference anyways. See http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html:)

Comment: Moreover SQLite will never enforce length specifications. If you declare a column as CHAR(n), VARCHAR(n), TEXT or STRING or (…) it has no length limitation.