# reading a sqlite database file and get the text from it C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app and I have a sqlite database file and I want to get it's text to backup it and the content of this file is unicode how to convert it to string

Comment: Why are you not just using the SQLite connector?

Comment: I have used a buffer to read the file content, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In SQLlite [everything is in unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930501/difference-between-varchar-nvarchar-in-sqlite), so you can't simply use `CAST (yourcolumn as Varchar(max))`. You have to do it in the C# using [Encoding.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.convert(VS.71).aspx)