# SQLite Many-to-Many Associative Tables for varying Attributes with varying Types

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

I am trying to create SQLite databases that are adaptable for multiple users, characterizing objects with unspecified characteristics.

Lets say its widgets, and these widgets can have multiple configurations, with different categories of attributes.

Some attribute categories will be common to all widgets, like "Weight" (a REAL), or "Description" (a TEXT).  Some will be specific to that kind of widget, like "Number of Teeth" (a REAL), "Color" (a TEXT), or "Whatever Real" (a REAL) or "However Text" (a TEXT).

All the other tables in the user's database have the same columns.  Its just at the "Widget_Configuration" table where things are different.  All other tables relate to the "Widget_Configuration" table.  If all users had the same kind of widget, with the same characteristics, it would be simple:  A column per Attribute.

But I want to combine these separate user databases.  It should be simple by having all tables relate to a unique Widget_Configuration.id.  But all the users are working with Widget_Configuration tables with different columns.

I'm inclined to think I should have an "Attributes" Table, with columns of "id", "Name", and "Value", and a "Widget_Configuration" table for "id","Widget_id", "Description".  And a an Associative table relating Widget_Config.id to Attribute.id.

But this means my Attributes.Value column will be populated by a mix of REAL and TEXT types.

How bad is that?  Is there a better way?

Comment: This is also known as [Entity-Attribute-Value or "EAV"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). If the set of attributes is fixed, the 'ideal' method in SQL is to avoid EAV. If using EAV, then it's a matter of how far down the rabbit-hole: either have separate `real` and `varchar` columns (same table or split) or store all `varchar` and parse as required. Standard DRI is not practical to enforce 'types'. In both cases it requires some form of client-side modeling to read/write attributes of the appropriate type.

Comment: tldr; It doesn't really matter for an EAV used for configurations. All such schema here is done with a singular `varchar` type (the 'actual type' is either specified in access or hidden behind the meta information). There is little reason to suspect that such configurations usage would benefit from slightly more compact `real` representations in the general case and the only real code difference is: `IsReal ? ParseReal(ReadCol()) : ReadCol()` vs `IsReal ? ReadRealCol() : ReadTextCol()`.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback.  EAV is a good lead.  From what I've read the description of EAV (being sparse) fits my situation really well.  This is a clue to figure out what I should be doing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930501/difference-between-varchar-nvarchar-in-sqlite